# Why are my DIVs not responding to my Javascript opacity function?

Tags: javascript, html, image, opacity, css

I've created a very simple javascript function where as I hover over certain words, elements with a certain `id` become transparent. This is working fine with my `img` tags, but `div`s with the same id are not changing?

Here is my javascript:

```
function revealCategory1() {
document.getElementById('c2').style.opacity="0.3";
document.getElementById('c3').style.opacity="0.3";
document.getElementById('c4').style.opacity="0.3";
}

function revealCategory2() {
document.getElementById('c1').style.opacity="0.3";
document.getElementById('c3').style.opacity="0.3";
document.getElementById('c4').style.opacity="0.3";
}

function revealCategory3() {
document.getElem..............etc

function resetReveal() {
document.getElementById('c1').style.opacity="1";
document.getElementById('c2').style.opacity="1";    
document.getElementById('c3').style.opacity="1";    
document.getElementById('c4').style.opacity="1";    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6XG2/

Which is being called by this html:

```
<div class="bars">
<span class="categories" id="c1" onMouseOver="revealCategory1()" onMouseOut="resetReveal()">VIDEO</span>
<span class="categories" id="c2" onMouseOver="revealCategory2()" onMouseOut="resetReveal()">ANIMATION</span>
<span class="categories" id="c3" onMouseOver="revealCategory3()" onMouseOut="resetReveal()">DESIGN</span>
<span class="categories" id="c4" onMouseOver="revealCategory4()" onMouseOut="resetReveal()">WEB-DESIGN</span>
</div>
```

On the page, this is working absolutely fine. The images go transparent.

```
<div class="logocontainer" >
<img class="logo" id="c1" src="images/DOSED-C1.png" />
<img class="logo" id="c2" src="images/DOSED-C2.png" />
<img class="logo" id="c3" src="images/DOSED-C3.png" />
<img class="logo" id="c4" src="images/DOSED-C4.png" />
</div>
```

But this is NOT, the `div`s don't go transparent.

```
<div class="maincontent">
<div id="c1" class="content" >VIDEO PIECE 1</div>
<div id="c2" class="content" >ANIMATION PIECE 1</div>
<div id="c3" class="content" >DESIGN PIECE 1</div>
<div id="c4" class="content" >WEB-DESIGN PIECE 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have duplicate (triplicate?) IDs in your page, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two (or more) elements with the same ID.

Have the images IDs named differently. i.e.:

```
<img class="logo" id="c1_image" src="images/DOSED-C1.png" />
```

Then, perform actions on both IDs:

```
function resetReveal() {
    document.getElementById('c1').style.opacity="1";
    document.getElementById('c1_image').style.opacity="1";
```

Also, remove those IDs from the `<spans>` in your `.bars` element. They don't do anything at the moment.

```
<span class="categories" onMouseOver="revealCategory1()" onMouseOut="resetReveal()">VIDEO</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say it but it is a pretty common mistake but All ID's have to be unique. Its the name tag that can be duplicated.

An alternative idea would be to use a class element and the document.getElementsByClassName method and then spool through the array thats returned picking out those elements you want, thats a good one for elements that don't allow the name tag.